# Show/hide element with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Hi i want to show and hide div element when i click on my button with angular using ng-click and ng-show. This is my code:

HTML

```
 <ons-page ng-controller="search">          
      <ons-button class="ion-android-search" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails"></ons-button>
      <input ng-show="showDetails" type="search" class="search-input" ng-model="search" placeholder="Buscar">
 </ons-page>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app');    
app.controller('search', function($scope){
    $scope.showDetails = true;
});
```

I try to use this example code: http://jsfiddle.net/asmKj/

This is my project: http://recorramisiones.com.ar/rutadelaselva/app/, go to "alojamientos" menu item to see my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Sory, doesnt show the search div...

Comment: Do you have this code inside your controller?  I assume you do.  Also, if you read the ngInit documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit you shouldn't use ng-init for this.

Comment: Your code works as it is. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/asmKj/373

Comment: I dont know how to use ng-init. I just follow your indications... i only try to follow the example in my question.

Comment: @isherwood in your example works great but in my project no, i dont know why

Comment: set the initial value to true? http://jsfiddle.net/asmKj/374/

Comment: @DevPat, i add the initial value in true, now show the field but when i click nothing happend... is rare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button is not within your `ng-controller`.

This part:

```
<ons-button class="ion-android-search ng-isolate-scope button effeckt-button button--large--cta slide-left" style="font-size:20px;" modifier="large--cta" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails">
```

is defined before this part:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="search" class="ng-scope">
```

So when you try to modify `showDetails` it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I update my question, the ng-controller is declared before ons-button.

Comment: right now I'm looking and your site, and there's no `ng-click` on the button and there's no `ng-show` on the input and there's no `ng-controller="search"`. The only `ng-controller` is on `<div class = "app-page alojamientos-page ng-scope">`